# CSS tag for slideshow on theme home page?

Tags: css

I am trying to move a slideshow downwards on a [theme](http://themeforest.net/item/newcastle-a-woocommerce-powered-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/3887883) but cannot identify the CSS tag to do so, when I type the following css it pushes the image but not the actual slideshow position:

```
.newcastle-carousel img {
margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close... Add the margin to the parent div, not just the `img`...

```
.newcastle-carousel-wrapper{
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.newcastle-carousel-wrapper {
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```